# How can we set Popup window Top to 40 dip?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How can I set Popup window top to 40 dip?

[image: popup menu]

My Popup menu code

```
 LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.llll);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
           (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
   changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
   changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);

   int OFFSET_X = -20;
   int OFFSET_Y = 40;

   changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout,
             Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.LEFT,OFFSET_Y);
```

Please suggest me how can I set popup menu top to 40 dip?

Comment: you are using popup window and in question title you have write popup menu. both is different.

Comment: Sorry bro..I am working on this problem at morning so i am  very confused

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `OFFSET_Y` to `40`. This value is in pixels. You need to set value in `dp` so you should do the following. Convert `40dp` to pixels:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int OFFSET_Y = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Rest remains the same. It should work fine.

Comment: I am using this code but noting changed **Resources r = getResources();
    int OFFSET_Y = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0,OFFSET_Y);**